# 'NgxMaskModule' does not appear to be an NgModule class

Tags: angular, material-ui, angular-material

My project stopped running after upgrading from version 14 to version 16 due to errors. I didn't bother to figure it out and upgraded further, to 17. The errors are still relevant and I have scoured the entire Internet in search of a solution.I was updating NgxMaskModule, and a myriad of errors fell down. I returned it back, because I think the same thing will happen with the rest of the dependencies:

> error NG6002: 'NgxMaskModule' does not appear to be an NgModule class.
>
> This likely means that the library (ngx-mask) which declares
> NgxMaskModule is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Chec k if a newer
> version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider
> checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected
> to be compatible with Ivy.

and there are many more similar errors below with other modules...

[image]

package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular-material-components/datetime-picker": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/animations": "^17.1.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/cli": "^17.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^17.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^17.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^17.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^17.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^17.1.0",
    "@angular/localize": "^17.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^17.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^17.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^17.1.0",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^5.0.2",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^13.1.1",
    "@ngrx/store": "^14.2.0",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.6",
    "angular8-yandex-maps": "^13.2.0",
    "animate.css": "^3.7.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "browser-sync": "^3.0.2",
    "jszip": "^3.10.1",
    "material-design": "0.0.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "ng-recaptcha": "^10.0.0",
    "ng2-pdf-viewer": "^6.4.1",
    "ngx-cookie": "^5.0.2",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^14.0.0",
    "ngx-image-cropper": "^6.3.1",
    "ngx-lightbox": "^2.3.0",
    "ngx-mask": "^12.0.0",
    "ngx-owl-carousel-o": "^14.0.1",
    "ngx-pagination": "^6.0.2",
    "ngx-quill": "^16.2.1",
    "ngx-toastr": "^18.0.0",
    "ngx-ui-loader": "^11.0.0",
    "oidc-client": "^1.11.5",
    "quill": "^1.3.7",
    "remove": "^0.1.5",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.7",
    "swiper": "^6.5.9",
    "tslib": "^1.14.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.14.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^17.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.20.11",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.22.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.22.0",
    "codelyzer": "^0.0.28",
    "eslint": "^7.25.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "jest-preset-angular": "^14.0.0",
    "protractor": "^7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "typescript": "~5.3.3"
  }
```

What have I already done?:

- Deleted the package-lock, node_modules, restart.
- "postinstall": "ngcc"
- rebooted in VSCode

Please help me